# Replace 2D mapping with numpy ufunc for efficiency

Tags: python, numpy

I've got a mapping array which takes a value as index and maps it to a previously-calculated value

Eg:
mapping[255] = 7

The task I want to perform is as follows:

```
width, height = ni.shape
for x in range(width):
    for y in range(height):
        NI_mapped[x][y] = mapping[ni[x][y]]
        RD_mapped[x][y] = mapping[rd[x][y]]
```

To give context, ni and rd are images loaded as ndarrays with integer values.

I want to speed up this operation using numpy ufuncs or another method to avoid having two for-loops.

I understand that if I were to use the function mapping is derived from, I could just do `NI_mapped = ni.vectorize(myfunc)`, however in this case the `myfunc` from which mapping is derived is expensive, so this is not practical.

Comment: Sounds like [advanced indexing](https://numpy.org/doc/1.18/reference/arrays.indexing.html#purely-integer-array-indexing) to me.

Comment: Can you provide some example data, to illustrate? _These integer values are in x,y positions in images._ Can the image be converted to an ndarray directly?

Comment: Sorry for being unclear, in this case the images (ni and rd) are already ndarrays containing integer values.
The code above is the functionality I want, I was just curious if such a thing was possible using ufuncs to increase performance.